# CodeIgniter form action not happening

Tags: php, codeigniter, action, form-submit

This is my code, once it's submitted it should in theory go to `localhost/site/main/login_validation`.

```
<?php
echo form_open('main/login_validation');
$emailData = array(
    'id' => 'inputEmail3',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'placeholder' => 'Email',
    'value' => 'email'
);
echo form_input($emailData);
$passwordData = array(
'id' => 'inputPassword3',
'class' => 'form-control',
'placeholder' => 'Password',
'value' => 'password'
);
echo form_password($passwordData);
$buttonData = array("type" => "submit", "class" => "btn btn-success btn-sm", "value" => "Login", 'name' => 'login_submit');
echo form_submit($buttonData, 'Login');

echo form_close(); 
 ?>
```

It sends me to `http://joeobrien.kd.io/ci_site/?email=Email%40domain.com&password=password123&login_submit=Login`, I assume I’ve made some simple mistake. [This link](http://joeobrien.kd.io/ci_site/) might show you the webpage if it's still online.

Comment: The code you posted here **IS NOT** the one that generates the form in the site you linked. Are you sure you're loading the right view?

Comment: @DamienPirsy Yeah I took out the html surrounding it, I didn't think it was relevant i've just listed the php.

Comment: @DamienPirsy, i've tried putting in the code from above but I have the same problems just the login part isn't styled.

Comment: There's a typo in the $emailData array ('value') ... also, none of your input fields have a name.

Comment: @foxmulder I fixed that but still no luck...

Comment: I tested the code you posted and everything works except the password and email fields are not sending data through post because you have not assigned them a name attribute.  If you fix that and there is still a problem perhaps the issue is elsewhere?  in your routes or a conflict in the html on the page?

Comment: If you're using codeigniter why not post the controller model and view to isolate the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the link you provided you seem to have a form within a form remove the outer one and it should work fine.

Comment: thanks, i'd tried to put a codeigniter form into a form I had from a while ago so I had that part left in my mistake. It's working now.